# Web Service for finding basic company info

Tags: web-services, stocks

I'm looking for a web service similar to StrikeIron Zacks Company Profile. In particular I'm looking for company headquarters based on company name or stock ticker. If anyone knows where Google, Yahoo, or StrikeIron find this information, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mergent Company Fundamentals API will do exactly what you need: http://www.mergent.com/servius/

Answer (score 0):

Dun & Bradstreet?  AFAIK, nothing they provide is free.